# How to implement @ mentions custom dropdown in Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, dropdown

I want to implement following feature like in most of social media networks in Angular 8.

[image: Sample of the feature I need to implement]

**This is the scenario:**

When user is typing inside a `<textarea>` whenever he type a `@` symbol then I want to show a dropdown in that specify place (place where the cursor is blinking).

I tried to find any `npm` packages but couldn't.

Any library or any solution to do this?

Comment: We cannot debug images, can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am showing sample of the feature which I need to implement in Angular 8. Can you suggest any approach or any npm package to do above feature?

Comment: Personally I would use Tailwind to create the search field & dropdown and on the search field use a filter pipe

Comment: Have you see this feature in Facebook. When we are typing when ever we type @ symbol then their will be a dropdown which we can select our friends. 

This is the same feature I need to implement in Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution for this. We can use following npm package to create above feature. Not the exact same thing, but some how it helps to resolve the issue.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-mentions